# UIBarButtonItem setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

**Updated**

I want to change offset between Arrow and Text in Back Button in Navigation Bar. It works just fine until I set

`UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = newAppearance`

Here is the full code:

```
        let appearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
        let standardAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        standardAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        standardAppearance.backgroundColor = someColor
        standardAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: titleColor]
        standardAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: titleColor]
        standardAppearance.shadowColor = navigationShadowColor

        // if remove theses 2 line, offset code works!!!
        appearance.standardAppearance = standardAppearance
        appearance.scrollEdgeAppearance = standardAppearance

        // code to set offset
        UIBarButtonItem
            .appearance()
            .setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(
                UIOffset(horizontal: -20, vertical: 0),
                for: .default)
```

Comment: Didn't you set/use `UINavigationBar.prefersLargeTitles`, because above appearance works only for standard titles?

Comment: @Asperi I checked in code and see that it is set in somewhere, but then it's turned off on viewDisappear, but I'll try turning it off everywhere (I'll do it today or tomorrow). Could you please post that as an answer, so it that helps I'm gonna mark your answer as correct ?

Comment: hack - Instead you add some space in your image at a side. Or put needed spaces in text.

Comment: I need negative spacing

Comment: I updated the code, because I found which line causes the issue, but don't know how to fix it "appearance.standardAppearance = standardAppearance"

Comment: I've got your situation, please see worked solution in answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UINavigationBar.appearance()` when specified overrides everything and has own settings for everything, so you need to configure offset via its own properties, like

```swift
...
standardAppearance.backButtonAppearance.normal.titlePositionAdjustment = 
    UIOffset(horizontal: -20, vertical: 0)

appearance.standardAppearance = standardAppearance
...
```

so the part of `UIBarButtonItem.appearance()` not needed - just remove it

Comment: I updated the question text, because I found which line causes the issue, could you please check one more time?

Comment: Man... I've lost 3 hours to solve this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set TitlePositionAdjustment in app delegate method "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" then it will be work.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIBarButtonItem
    .appearance()
    .setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(
        UIOffset(horizontal: -20, vertical: 0),
        for: .default)
    return true
}
```

Comment: I think I'm doing just the same but not in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I'm gonna check that in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions today or tomorrow

Comment: Yes, you are doing same, but you need to put that code in AppDelegate.

Comment: sure, I'll check that and reply here, thank you for a suggestion

Comment: no, it doesn't help. And in general it doesn't matter when in the app you set Appearance But if you set it when UI Appeared, you need to pop (dismiss) this screen, so Appearance will be applied

Comment: I updated the question text, because I found which line causes the issue, could you please check one more time?

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for a custom back button

```
func addBackButton() {
    let backButtonView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 44))
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "back-arrow"))
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: -5, y: 11, width: 12, height: 22)
    imageView.image = imageView.image!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    imageView.tintColor = .fiGreen()
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: 60, height: 44))
    label.textColor = .fiGreen()
    label.text = NSLocalizedString("back", comment: "Back")
    backButtonView.addSubview(imageView)
    backButtonView.addSubview(label)
    backButtonView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(backButtonClicked)))
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButtonView)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
}
```

I think you can modify it to have the offset that you need.

Comment: I don't want to use leftBarButtonItem (it has different offset from the edge), I don't want to use UIBarButtonItem with custom view (because for different iOS versions one needs to fix offset difference between System back button and custom), I just need to set offsets of backBarButtonItem

Comment: I updated the question text, because I found which line causes the issue, could you please check one more time?